# How do I parse a Date to a long with am/pm?

Tags: java, datetime, date, time, simpledateformat

I want to parse my date like "yyyy-mm-dd-hh:mm:ss". And I want to get a long back.

My code is:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh:mm:ss").parse(exampleDate);
long longDate = date.getTime();
```

This is working if hh > 12. But if not I'll get for 12:00 o'clock an 00:00.
What's wrong?

Comment: What programming language are we talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use HH for 24 hr clock

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 0):

`hh` should be `HH` if you use 24 hours format.